Python integration inside of a function
I have a question related to the scipy.integrate.quad method: Say I have a base function with two nested function using quad method, and I need two output values from that. But you have to define the variable of the big function to output the values.
For instance, I want something like this:
from scipy.integrate import quad

def myfunction(x):
    function_0 = 1.25 * x ** 2
    function_1 = function_0 * 9.81 + 2 * x
    myreturn1 = function_1 * np.pi
    myreturn2 = function_1 * np.pi ** 2
    return quad(myreturn1, 0, np.inf)[0], quad(myreturn2, 0, np.inf)[0]

val1, val2 = myfunction(x)

When I call this function you have to define a variable 'x' otherwise it output error.
Is there a better way of doing this?

I'm not sure if this works at all even if you define the variable x, because the variables which  you have named "function" are not functions.

I don't want to define x, i need to solve x , if i dont use def myfunction at all, just use myreturn and quad function to solve it , it will work, or just define myfunction(x) to return a whole function, then use val1 = quad(myfunction, 0, 1),this way will work. But i want to make the quad()be nested in a bigger function. I'm not sure if im being clear

quad expects a function as a first argument, but function_0, function_1, and consequently myreturn1 and myreturn2 are just expressions (most likely evaluating to a number if you provide a number as x).
You should define all of them as functions as well. You can define one function in terms of another function by calling it inside:
from scipy.integrate import quad

def function_0(x):
    return 1.25 * x ** 2

def function_1(x):
    return function_0(x) * 9.81 + 2 * x

def myreturn1(x):
    return function_1(x) * np.pi

def myreturn2(x):
    return function_1(x) * np.pi ** 2

def myfunction():
    return quad(myreturn1, 0, np.inf)[0], quad(myreturn2, 0, np.inf)[0]

val1, val2 = myfunction()


This can also be done within myfunction using lambdas. That would require the least modification.
